# left join finding matching ID

Tags: php, sql, join

I have 2 tables that i want to left join but i don't know what to do when im gonna find a ID to ref from both tables `ON ".$FT.".userid = ".$MT.".to_id` i cant because in messageThread SESSION id could either be to_id or from_id depending on who started the conversation (msg_thread)... is there a way to do this inside the query (SQL) or do i have to add another query above this one and find the id SESSION matches to?

1. table is friends
2. table is messagethread

here is the code:

```
$FT = $table['friends'];    
$MT = $table['messagethread'];

$query = "SELECT userid, status, fuserid, to_id, from_id
          FROM ".$FT." 
          LEFT JOIN ".$MT."
          ON ".$FT.".userid = ".$MT.".to_id
          WHERE userid = ? && status = ? && (to_id = ? OR from_id = ?)";
$params = array($_SESSION['USER_ID'], '2', $_SESSION['USER_ID'], $_SESSION['USER_ID']);
$results = dataQuery($query, $params);
```

Comment: Make the decision on `to_id` or `from_id` in PHP and then tailor the query to match your requirement before issuing it.

Answer (score 0):

try to make the where condition to be like that

```
WHERE .$_SESSION['USER_ID']. IN (userid, to_id, from_id)
```